# django AttributeError when querying data from the database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I keep getting *AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'* error whenever i use `obj=Userpost.objects.all()` . How will i format it so that i can use it to query all data in the database? this is my snippet code

```
    obj=Userpost.objects.all()
context={
'title':obj.title,
'content':obj.content,
'date':obj.date,

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching it in the wrong way. Your `obj` is a `QuerySet` object, so basically it contains many object. You are probably thinking that you are passing attributes of every single object, but actually you are trying to get such attributes from `QuerySet`.

Change it to:

```
posts = Userpost.objects.all()
context = {
    'posts': posts
}
```

Then in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.content }}
    {{ post.date }}
{% endfor %}
```